# How can i remove a part of a line of a big log file

Tags: bash, logging

i have a 15000+ lines log and i want to remove a part of every line

#### This a what my log looks like

```
15 {"level":"warn","message":"warn: Player: 819631980014075905 | Track has been started playing [\u001b[34m34mSomethingElse2\u001b[39m]"}
12 {"level":"warn","message":"warn: Player: 819631980014075905 | Track has been started playing [\u001b[34m34mSomething2\u001b[39m]"}
1 {"level":"warn","message":"warn: Player: 819631980014075905 | Track has been started playing [\u001b[34m34mSomethingElse\u001b[39m]"}
3 {"level":"warn","message":"warn: Player: 819631980014075905 | Track has been started playing [\u001b[34mSomething\u001b[39m]"}
```

#### What i want the log to look like

```
15 SomethingElse2
12 Something2
1 SomethingElse
3 Something
```

I realized I could use the find/replace function of almost any text editor.

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized I could use the find/replace function of almost any text editor.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious candidate is of course `sed`. It depends a bit on what you used to display the input-lines (especially the `\u001b` might give some trouble), but

```
sed 's/\{.*34m34m//;s/.u001b.*//`
```

You may want to put it through the same filter that you used to display the lines.